# What's the best practice to throw an Exception in Flutter

Tags: flutter, exception

I have an exception that gets thrown multiple times before getting handled in my code, (the same error object gets thrown 4 times in the tree).

During each throw , flutter appends the word `Exception:`  to my error object, so the final shape of the message is:
`Exception: Exception: Exception: Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 10.12.7.15, port = 39682`

And this is an example of how I handle exceptions:

```
getSomeData () async {
  try {
    await myFunction3();
  } catch (e) {
    throw Exception(e);
  }
}
/*****************************************/
Future<void> myFunction3 () async {
  try {
    await myFunction2();
  } catch (e) {
    throw Exception(e);
  }
}
/*****************************************/
Future<void> myFunction2 () async {
  try {
    await myFunction1();
  } catch (e) {
    throw Exception(e);
  }
}
/*****************************************/
Future<void> myFunction1() async {
  try {
    await dio.get(/*some parameters*/);
  }
  on DioError catch (e) {
    throw Exception(e.error);
  }
  catch (e) {
    throw Exception(e);
  }
}
```

I want to throw the Exception() in a right way so the repetition of word `Exception:`  doesn't appear anymore in my error string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of throwing a new exception, you could rethrow the catched one:

```dart
Future<void> myFunction1() async {
  try {
    await dio.get(/*some parameters*/);
  }
  on DioError catch (e) {
    // do something
    rethrow;
  }
  catch (e) {
    // do something
    rethrow;
  }
}
```

See more: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-rethrow-to-rethrow-a-caught-exception

Comment: No. In my code if `dio.get` resolves to a failure, it goes to `catch` block. `catch` block explicitly says to rethrow the received exception.